# Gitlab: How to run a deploy job on a tagged version / release?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have created several releases of my backend service in gitlab. Now I want to be able to pick one of them and run the deployment job in my gitlab pipeline on it. SO that the specific version gets deployed. (I'm creating release notes to each release so I can pick which release should now get deployed.)

[image: my releases]

This is my deployment job in the gitlab-ci.yml:

[image: deployment job]

So far I have used this job like this: When a feature branch was merged into the master and the stand could be deployed and passed all the tests, then the job was triggered manually in the pipeline overview page. Now that I'm using tags to tag each new master version, I want to be able to deploy a version/release from the tags.

Does anyone have an idea how this could work in principle? It would be best if I had a dropdown menu where I can select one of the releases and then trigger the deployment job for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job needs to not get run in the master pipeline, but in the tags pipeline

```
only:
    refs:
      - tags
when: manual
```

This way I can copy the tag of the version that I want to deploy:

[image]

and search for it in the pipelines overview page to then trigger the deploy job manually:

[image]