# how to differentiate when the MR is accepted

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I'd like to have a branch in the deployment script of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that is based on whether the particular pipeline is run because a MR has been accepted and is being merged into the default branch.

For instance,

```
Deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: alpine
  script:
    - apk add openssh-client
    - install -d -D -m 700 -p ~/.ssh
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - cat "${MY_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" | ssh-add  -
    - if [ "${CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH}" = "${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}" ]; then \
         rsync $BUILD_DIR/myfile.tar.gz filestore1 ; \
       else \
         rsync $BUILD_DIR/myfile.tar.gz filestore2 ; \
       fi
```

I don't think that the comparison of `CI_DEFAULT*` with `CI_COMMIT*` is a safe comparison. I believe this works anytime a commit is on the default branch, not when being merged, so I think I'm missing an important distinction and/or a best-practice.

My intent is that so long as the MR is still in dev, it should be pushed to `filestore2`, and only pushed to the production `filestore1` when the MR is good, tests good/complete, and is accepted.

Related:

- [Gitlab: How to run a deploy job on a tagged version / release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69334085/gitlab-how-to-run-a-deploy-job-on-a-tagged-version-release) requires me to tag when I need to release something; this may be something I work into my workflow, but is not our current workflow

Comment: So you want the deploy to run _before_ the merge, but _after_ the MR is approved? OR you only want it to run on the default branch -- but only as the result of an MR being merged (and not when commits are pushed directly without an MR)? Or maybe I've misunderstood and it's something else you're looking for.

Comment: The `deploy` stage is the last of multiple must-pass stages: if it gets that far, then we want it to auto-deploy (rsync) the tarball. What I want to happen is if the pipeline is due to a merge request approval (merge onto the default branch), then it will rsync to the production filestore; otherwise it deploys to the dev filestore. Does that clear it up? (Perhaps I'm munging how an auto-deploy should be done ... I thought the last stage of a successful pipeline should be the optional deployment.) Thanks @sytech

Comment: It is a valid workflow to deploy to prod from the MR pipeline (and you can check for approvals before deploying), but some hazards can exist in this workflow. For example, if you have two 'feature' branches (or whatever you want to call them), if both of these branches deploy, only one change set can be incorporated at a time. You may also miss changes that have been merged into the default branch, but not in the feature branch (e.g., when you are 1 or more commits "behind" the default branch). Another small mechanical issue is that approvals can't trigger jobs/pipelines, so it will be manual.

Comment: But normally, you would just deploy from the default branch after the merge -- which appears to be what your job would do. I think the code you have makes sense for the purpose you describe. When changes are merged to the default branch `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` will be the same as `CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH` and the condition you have would evaluate to true, causing it to dpeloy to `filestore1` -- for pipelines running on any other branch, `filestore2` would be used.

Comment: Thanks @sytech, I appreciate the info! I think that resolves the question, if you transcribe your comments to answer, I'll accept.

Comment: (For clarity, though, I still need to deploy for non-default branches, just to a different place.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have makes sense to fulfill the purpose you described and should work as-is (assuming the bash code is otherwise well-formed).

When changes are merged to the default branch, `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` will be the same as `CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH` and the condition you have would evaluate to true, causing it to deploy to `filestore1` -- for pipelines running on any other branch, `filestore2` would be used when this job runs.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be as follows, this way `filestore1` will be pushed **only** when MR is merged to main or master, or else `filestore2` will be pushed.

```
Deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: alpine
  script:
    - apk add openssh-client
    - install -d -D -m 700 -p ~/.ssh
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - cat "${MY_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" | ssh-add  -
    - if [ "${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}" -eq "main" ] |  [ "${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}" -eq "master" ]; then \
         rsync $BUILD_DIR/myfile.tar.gz filestore1 \
       else \
         rsync $BUILD_DIR/myfile.tar.gz filestore2 \
       fi
```

The if statement checks for master or main here.

Comment: I think the only difference between the yaml in my question and this answer is that you have taken the dynamic variable `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` and converted it into a static string. While this will work for many repos, it does not work for those (perhaps legacy) repos where the default branch is still named `"master"`.

Comment: Updated the code to include master branch